# I need to block a certain URL in Squid3

Tags: squid

I need to block a certain url on my squid3 proxy server.

I can block bbc like this

```
.bbc.co.uk
```

But that blocks ALL of the bbc website I want only to block www.bbc.co.uk/news

This is what I use to block sites

```
acl block dstdomain "/etc/squid3/block.acl"
--Then further down-- 
http_access deny block
```

As it would seem I solved it myself

```
acl blockurls url_regex "/etc/squid3/block/urls.acl
--Further Down--
http_access deny blockurls
```

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer, and accept it, to make it clear that the problem is solved. (The answer could be useful for others, which makes it worth keeping.)

Answer (score 1):

As it would seem I solved it myself

```
acl blockurls url_regex "/etc/squid3/block/urls.acl
# 
# later on in the file
#
http_access deny blockurls
```